# Fill 20 textboxes with random array elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so I'm trying to create a userscript that will prefill 20 textboxes with a random element of an array. I have this line of code here:

```
$("textarea").val(nottrashy[Math.floor(Math.random() * nottrashy.length)]);
```

which I'm trying to modify to make the textboxes all get a different random element, not the same random element.  All of the textboxes have the same value, so I can't target individual ones.  Can anyone help?

Comment: If you are interested in learning - "jquery each" and "JavaScript shuffle array" would be good search terms to construct an answer. Otherwise just wait for copy-paste-ready code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I knew the answer had to do with a method I didn't know about.  Thanks for guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: @Babadooba as a rule of thumb: setting anything using jQuery (like `.val(value)`, `.css(style)` etc) sets the same value to every element in the collection. Getting (like `.val()`, `.css()`) returns the value for the first element in the collection. If you want to work with each element separately you should use `.each`.

Comment: Is there a better method I should be using inside the each method to set the values instead of .val?

Comment: @Babadooba when working with form elements you can use `this.value = something` (which is just plain JavaScript) instead of `$(this).val( something )`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate the textareas using [**.each**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and then try to assign the value of each element.

```
var yourTextAreas = $("#someparentelement").find("textarea.someclass");

$.each(yourTextAreas, function(){
    $(this).val('your unique number logic');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try to implement this.